# How to get method name from URL using codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

How to get method name from URL using codeigniter 3. I heard that `$this->router->method;` is deprecated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `$this->router->method` included in ver 3, previously it was method `$this->router->fetch_method();`

See [this](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s334/sh/afb403b3-c076-4e3f-8b0c-2107ad314f30/d00a81c7a97a7a899946695c8f386603) ([page link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html?highlight=fetch_method)) - Hope this helps.